# The induced equivalence of bimodules from Morita equivalence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, morita-equivalence

Let $A$ be a finite dimension algebra over a field K. $B=eAe$ is Morita equivalent to $A$ for an idempotent $e \in A$. Then Morita equivalence $F$ is given by $F(M)=eM$ for any left $A$-module $M$.

I have seen that "The induce equivalence from the category of $A$-bimodules to the category of $eAe$-bimodules is then given by $W \rightarrow eWe$ for any $A$-bimodule $W$." My questions are:

1. $F$ maps $A$-bimodules to $eAe$-bimodules, but why $F:A$-bimodules $\rightarrow eAe$-bimodules is also equivalent?
2. Why $F(W)=eWe$ for any bimodules of $A$?

Comment: To have a Morita equivalence you also need to assume that $e$ is a *full* projection, that is, $AeA=A$.

Comment: Why do I need that $AeA=A$?

Comment: Otherwise you lose information. Take a direct product R=AxB.  Then A is eRe for e=(1,0) but is usually not MoritA equivalent to A. The condition Ruy gives us needed to get essential surjectivity.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg $B=eAe$ Morita equivalent to $A$ is a condition, not a conclusion.

Comment: You asked why AeA=A is needed. This is equivalent to A is Morita equivalent to eAe.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg  Thank you. I don't know that conclusion.

Comment: Also once you know AeA=A you should check A\otimes A(e\otimes e)A\otimes A=A\otimes A to get the bimodule result

Comment: The left adjoint of V to eV is W to Ae\otimes\{eAe}W and the counit of the adjunction is the action map. So if you have an equivalence Ae\otimes_{eAe}eA to A is surjective with image AeA. So A=AeA. Conversely if A=AeA you can prove the counit is always an isomorphism.

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg Since $A$-bimodules are equivalent to $A\otimes A^{op}$-modules. And $F(M)=eM$ for any left $A$-module $M$. Then $F(M)=Me$ for right $A$-modules. So $F(W)=eWe$. Then my questions are solved. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly